# Z3 Java Possible Memory Leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, z3, smt

I have a strange memory problem with Java library of Z3 which I couldn't figure where the problem is. Oddly, I can't reproduce the problem on a Windows machine where I have Java 7 (I most probably have slightly older version of Z3 there though). The problem occurs on a MacOSx 10.6.8 with Java 6 and Z3 v4.3.2. I have an application that uses Z3 for analysis. I tracked the following piece of code as the (initial) source of the problem:

```
Symbol eNames = con.mkSymbol(domainName);           
Symbol[] symbols = new Symbol[values.length];
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) symbols[i] = con.mkSymbol(values[i]);
System.out.println("Before ENUMSORT");
//EnumSort eSort = con.mkEnumSort(domainName, values);
EnumSort eSort = con.mkEnumSort(eNames,symbols);
System.out.println("After ENUM SORT ...");
```

When I run the application I get the following after "Before ENUMSORT" is printed:

```
java(55938,0x100501000) malloc: *** error for object 0x10200f1b8: incorrect    checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I know this is not a good way of debugging especially when there is a memory problem but it is very difficult to debug the code since it originates from JNI. When I look at the Z3 code here (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/api_datatype.cpp) I couldn't figure what the source of the problem is. I assume that the method Z3_mk_enumeration_sort is called from mkEnumSort method in Java. When I change the call of mkEnumSort in my code to a form like

```
 EnumSort eSort = con.mkEnumSort(domainName,new String[]{"X","Y"});
```

the problem seems gone. What do you think, what could be the source of the problem?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There have been a number of bugfixes for the Java API since the 4.3.2 release. There is no newer official master release though, so before going any further, I have to ask you to upgrade to the unstable branch (source and binaries available on codeplex; not migrated to github yet).

Comment: I got the unstable code from here (http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), however couldn't build the binaries. make gives the following error: g++ -o z3  shell/datalog_frontend.o .....  math/polynomial/polynomial.a util/util.a  -lpthread -L/opt/local/lib -fopenmp
ld: duplicate symbol rewriter_tpl<fpa2bv_rewriter_cfg>::frame_stack()         in smt/smt.a(smt_setup.o) and tactic/fpa/fpa_tactics.a(fpa2bv_tactic.o)
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [z3] Error 1

Comment: For the source code, please get the unstable version from the new repository at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3 , we're currently migrating to github and the source has been moved (new bugfixes not on codeplex anymore). What system are you trying to compile on, and what's your compiler's make and model?

Comment: I have updated my system to MacOSX 10.9.5 and installed Java 8 (among other things) just to eliminate any further doubts. The code compiled without problems but I still get the same error. There is more information from JRE this time that I can't paste (there is a log file). I don't know if it will be any useful, if so I can try to send it by e-mail or some other way you prefer.

Comment: I still can't reproduce this problem, neither on Windows nor on OSX. Could you perhaps send me that log file by email or maybe use pastebin so others can see it too?

Comment: I pasted log file [here](http://pastebin.com/LRFtw0sz). As I mentioned previously I had no problem on Windows either but on MacOSX 10.9.5 with Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for the log, but I'm still unable to reproduce the problem. We had weird memory problems with gcc version 4.9.x due to compiler bugs. Which compiler are you using to compile Z3?

Comment: Sorry for the latency on this. The problem went away when I installed a newer version of Xcode (i.e. clang). Thanks for the tip.